# How to get device model name in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) plugin to get device info
but I couldn't get the model name.

the device name is changing and the

> utsname.machine

don't give me the right name

what to do to get the right device name in a flutter project.

Answer (score 8):

How about using [apple_product_name](https://github.com/kyle-seongwoo-jun/flutter_apple_product_name) package?

```dart
import 'package:apple_product_name/apple_product_name.dart';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  final info = await DeviceInfoPlugin().iosInfo;
  print(info.utsname.machine);      // "iPhone15,2"
  print(info.utsname.productName);  // "iPhone 14 Pro"
}
```

You can get the model name of iOS devices.

FYI, I'm author of this package.

Comment: I use my Iphone 11 and it doesn't show information that says Iphone 11 in every attribute of `deviceInfo.iosInfo`. Where do we get exact model of our phone? thanks

Answer (score 4):

For those who face such an issue I used [Apple's mobile device codes](https://gist.github.com/adamawolf/3048717) to display the device model name from the machine code

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
var device = UniversalPlatform.isAndroid ? await deviceInfo.androidInfo : await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
deviceData = device.toMap();
String model = deviceData['model']
```

Comment: This gave me //e.g. iPhone, not like //e.g. iPhone 11 pro max

Comment: use deviceData['name']

Comment: sorry, not working

Comment: Any other suggestions?